# How to Implement File System Cache in codenameone

Tags: java, codenameone

I need to write Files for caching. as you know there is no such a File System on codenameone. but i want to implement File System Cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codename One has a file system API: `FileSystemStorage`. It also has a `Storage` API which is a flat filesystem like API. Both can be used for file cache.

It also has a class called `CacheMap` for easy caching and `URLImage` which download/caches downloaded images. There is also `ImageDownloadService` which does the same but with a different architecture.

And there is the `CachedDataService` class as well.

Comment: Thank you so much, I implement with FileSystemStorage API but somehow i have some problems with some android devices and ios. I was thinking about Storage API. Is it better to work with Storage API? Is it handle the location of storage or not?

Comment: Storage is a flat hierarchy with no folders. Choose whatever suits your needs.